# Find distinct real numbers satisfying $\frac{xy}{x-y} = \frac{1}{30}$ and $\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{2018}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

> Figure out with distinct real numbers the system of equations.
>
> $$\frac{xy}{x-y} = \frac{1}{30}$$
> $$\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{2018}$$

I multiplied x-y both side on the first equation and square on both side, and I stucked.

Help me...

Comment: I would try squaring the first equation and then comparing it to the second.

Comment: The 2018 suggests that this is a contest problem. Please provide a source, so that we know the contest isn't on-going.

Comment: @Blue It's [not our responsibility to find that out](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11189/290189).  However, if *you* are *sure* that it's an *ongoing* contest problem, you may flag it for moderator's attention so that it'll be temporarily closed.

Answer (score 3):

Inverting the equations gives
$$
30  = \frac{x-y}{xy} = \frac 1y - \frac 1x \\
2018 = \frac{x^2+x^2}{x^2y^2} = \frac 1{y^2} + \frac 1{x^2}
$$
This suggests to substitute $a= \frac 1x, b= \frac 1y$:
$$
 30 = b - a \\
 2018 = b^2 + a^2 \, 
$$
This leads to a simple quadratic equation for $a$ (or $b$) which has two different real (actually 
integral) solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x,y\ne0$,
we can use $u=1/x$, $v=1/y$:
\begin{align} 
v-u &= 30
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
v^2+u^2 &= 2018
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\eqref{2}-\eqref{1}^2:\quad
2uv&=1118
,\\
v^2+u^2+2uv &= 2018+1118
,\\
(u+v)^2&=56^2
,\\
u+v&=\pm56
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Combination of \eqref{3} with \eqref{1} 
provides two cases:

Case 1.

\begin{align} 
v-u &= 30
,\\
v+u&=56
,\\
u&=13
\quad v=43
,\\
x&=\frac1{13},\quad y=\frac1{43}
.
\end{align}

Case 2.

\begin{align} 
v-u &= 30
,\\
v+u&=-56
,\\
u&=-43
\quad v=-13
,\\
x&=-\frac1{43},\quad y=-\frac1{13}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation we get:
$$30xy=x-y$$ or $$y(30x+1)=x$$ so $$y=\frac{x}{30x+1}$$ substituting this in the second equation we get
$${\frac {1}{2018}}\,{\frac { \left( 43\,x+1 \right)  \left( 13\,x-1
 \right) }{450\,{x}^{2}+30\,x+1}}
=0$$ Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{xy}{x-y} & = & \frac{1}{30}\\
\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} & = & \frac{1}{2018}
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow 
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
900 x^2y^2 & = & x^2+y^2-2 xy\\
2018x^2y^2 & = & x^2+y^2
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow x y = \frac{1}{559}
$$

etc.